# Apache Spark -- Data Grouping and Execution in worker nodes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

We are getting live machine data as json and we get this data from RabbitMQ. below is a sample of the json,

```css
{"DeviceId":"MAC-1001","DeviceType":"Sim-1","TimeStamp":"05-12-2017 10:25:35","data":{"Rate":10,"speed":2493,"Mode":1,"EMode":2,"Run":1}}
{"DeviceId":"MAC-1001","DeviceType":"Sim-1","TimeStamp":"05-12-2017 10:25:36","data":{"Rate":10,"speed":2493,"Mode":1,"EMode":2,"Run":1}}
{"DeviceId":"MAC-1002","DeviceType":"Sim-1","TimeStamp":"05-12-2017 10:25:37","data":{"Rate":10,"speed":2493,"Mode":1,"EMode":2,"Run":1}}
{"DeviceId":"MAC-1002","DeviceType":"Sim-1","TimeStamp":"05-12-2017 10:25:38","data":{"Rate":10,"speed":2493,"Mode":1,"EMode":2,"Run":1}}
```

The data is windowed for duration of 'X' minutes and then below is what we want to achieve

1. Group the data by deviceId, this is done but not sure if we can get a DataSet
2. We want to loop through the above grouped data and execute for aggregation logic for each device using the foreachPartition so that the code is executed within worker nodes.

Please correct me if my thought process is wrong here.

Our earlier code was collecting the data,looping through the RDD's,convert them to DataSet and applying aggregation logic on the DataSet using Spark SqlContext api's.

When doing load testing we saw 90% of the processing was happening in Master node and after a while the cpu usage spiked to 100% and the process bombed out.

So we are now trying to re-engineer the whole process to execute maximum of logic in worker nodes.

Below is the code so far that actually works in worker node but we are yet to get a DataSet for aggregating Logic

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  try {
   
   mconf = new SparkConf();
   mconf.setAppName("OnPrem");
   mconf.setMaster("local[*]");
   
   JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(mconf);
     
   jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(60));

   SparkSession spksess = SparkSession.builder().appName("Onprem").getOrCreate();
   //spksess.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");
   
   Map<String, String> rabbitMqConParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
   rabbitMqConParams.put("hosts", "localhost");
   rabbitMqConParams.put("userName", "guest");
   rabbitMqConParams.put("password", "guest");
   rabbitMqConParams.put("vHost", "/");
   rabbitMqConParams.put("durable", "true");
   
   List<JavaRabbitMQDistributedKey> distributedKeys = new LinkedList<JavaRabbitMQDistributedKey>();
   distributedKeys.add(new JavaRabbitMQDistributedKey(QUEUE_NAME, new ExchangeAndRouting(EXCHANGE_NAME, "fanout", ""), rabbitMqConParams));
   
   Function<Delivery, String> messageHandler = new Function<Delivery, String>() {

    public String call(Delivery message) {
     return new String(message.getBody());
    }
   };
   
   JavaInputDStream<String> messages = RabbitMQUtils.createJavaDistributedStream(jssc, String.class, distributedKeys, rabbitMqConParams, messageHandler);
   
   JavaDStream<String> machineDataRDD = messages.window(Durations.minutes(2),Durations.seconds(60)); //every 60 seconds one RDD is Created
   machineDataRDD.print();
   
   JavaPairDStream<String, String> pairedData = machineDataRDD.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<String, String>(getMap(s).get("DeviceId").toString(), s)); 
   
   JavaPairDStream<String, Iterable<String>> groupedData = pairedData.groupByKey(); 
   
   groupedData.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaPairRDD<String,Iterable<String>>>(){

    @Override
    public void call(JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<String>> data) throws Exception {
     
     data.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<Tuple2<String,Iterable<String>>>>(){

      @Override
      public void call(Iterator<Tuple2<String, Iterable<String>>> data) throws Exception {
       
        while(data.hasNext()){
         LOGGER.error("Machine Data == >>"+data.next());
        }
      }
      
     });
      
    }
   
   });
   jssc.start();
   jssc.awaitTermination();
   
  }
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

The below grouping code gives us a Iterable of string for a Device , ideally we would like to get a DataSet

```js
JavaPairDStream<String, String> pairedData = machineDataRDD.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<String, String>(getMap(s).get("DeviceId").toString(), s));
JavaPairDStream<String, Iterable<String>> groupedData = pairedData.groupByKey();
```

Important thing for me is the looping using foreachPartition so that code executing gets pushed to Worker Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through more code samples and guidelines sqlcontext , sparksession are not serialized and available on the worker nodes , so we will be changing the strategy of not trying to build a dataset withing foreachpartition loop.